# C++ instansing a struct error, why isn't this allowed?

Tags: c++, mingw

I'm using the following struct in my program.

```
struct terminator{
    int id;
    string type;
    union{
        terminator *next;
        int empty;
    };
};
```

In main I have the following code:

```
int main(){
    terminator root = {0, "", NULL};
    root = {0, "", NULL}; //NOT ALLOWED WHY? Trying to set to its original value.
}
```

This gives the following error message:

```
g++ lab8.cc -std=c++11
lab8.cc: In function 'int main()':
lab8.cc:78:21: error: no match for 'operator=' in 'root = {0, "", 0}'
lab8.cc:78:21: note: candidates are:
lab8.cc:6:8: note: terminator& terminator::operator=(const terminator&)
lab8.cc:6:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<brace-enclosed in
itializer list>' to 'const terminator&'
lab8.cc:6:8: note: terminator& terminator::operator=(terminator&&)
lab8.cc:6:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<brace-enclosed in
itializer list>' to 'terminator&&'
```

But this is ok instead:

```
int main(){
    terminator root = {0, "", NULL};
    root = *(new terminator);
    root.id=0;
    root.type="";
    root.next=NULL;
}
```

Why is this so? Any way to get around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, you are **initializing** the structure.

In the second case, you are trying to **assign** to the variable already declared, and unless your compiler supports compound literals as an extension, that won't work. (Even if it does, you would need to write

```
root = (terminator){ 0, "", NULL };
```

to actually make it work.)

**If you can use C++11** (which it seems you do), you can also take advantage of the new feature called "initializer lists" which sport a similar syntax:

```
root = terminator{ 0, "", NULL };
```

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but in C++11 the use of `NULL` is deprecated in favour of `nullptr`.

Comment: @Gorpik That's interesting. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the compiler that the RHS is of type `terminator`:

```
root = terminator{0, "", NULL};
```

Comment: @H2CO3 OP is using a C++11 compiler.

Comment: Oh, I see. Didn't notice the `-std=c++11` flag. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

The line `terminator root = {0, "", NULL};` does aggregate initialization, which is a form of construction allowed in the absence of a constructor. The `=` there does not really imply assignment. In C++11 you can use the brace syntax to construct an anonymous temporary object of type `terminator`, which you can then assign to `root`:

```
root = terminator{0, "", nullptr};
```